# Why are some edges not appearing in my Freestyle render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle, svg

I'm using the FreeStyle plugin to export/create SVG files from 3D objects. But, note that inside certain objects some lines do not appear. Look at the attached pictures.

[image]

[image]

PS: I tried using only the 'contour' attribute, and also using the others of the Edge types tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select those edges and mark them as Freestyle edges. Then tick the Edge Mark option.
[image]

Alternatively you can probably tweak the crease angle, but you may get unwanted lines.